# HTML displays differently in JSP vs. HTML file

Tags: html, css, jsp, button

I have what amounts to very basic HTML inside of a JSP page of my Java web-app.  The crux of what I'm trying to do is wrap text in an input button of fixed width (IE7).  It does not work in my JSP (the text is cutoff).  However, if I create an HTML file and open it with the same browser, it works fine.  The contents of the .JSP and .HTML are the same, as posted below.  What am I missing here?  Shouldn't they behave the same?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="A lot of descriptive text on a button" style="width:100px; white-space:normal;" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Compare the source of each example after clicking view-source in the browser. Perhaps your web app is inserting some extra bits.

Comment: Just tried a WinMerge of saved "View Source" for both and they match identically.

Comment: Furthermore, I can open the (JSP) page from the web browser (no wrapping), click View Source, save it to the desktop, and when I open the saved HTML file it wraps fine!

Comment: Doesnt make sense, try this: open both pages side by side. Click the first and press ctrl + 0, then do the same with the second. Just in case your browser is zoomed in for that URL

Comment: It made the text larger by a bit in both, but the result is the same - one wraps, one doesn't wrap.